# Demo infrastructure faisability

Tags: azure, printing, android, endpoint

I would like to ask if it's possible to use an Android Phone as Hotspot and with the VPN enabled ?

My aim is to connect by WIFI a printer and in the other hand to have connectivity to an Azure VPN Endpoint to use a PrintServer solution into the cloud.

Do you thinks it's possible ?

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards.

Narglix

Comment: You mean a local printjob, of some meg or gig, will transit locally to the cloud, to come back to the printer ? Whats your goal to such use ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I've done this with OpenVPN and would imagine it will work with any VPN.

Under the hood, Android is running Linux, and when hotspotting is acting as an AP + router. Android sees a VPN as a virtual Internet interface.

You will need to get your routes correct for everything to work of-course.